# "Files <FolderName> is ready" prompt on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: directory, 18.04, gnome-shell

Every time I open a folder from the desktop, a prompt is shown that the said folder is opened. How do I stop that?

Comment: how are you 'opening a folder from the desktop'

Answer (score 8):

You may use a [GNOME Shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[NoAnnoyance](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/)" to remove the "Files  is Ready" notification. It also puts the newly launched window into focus.

---

Other similar extensions:

- ['Window Is Ready' Notification Remover](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/)
- [Focus my window](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1005/focus-my-window/).
- another [NoAnnoyance](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/) (for newer versions of GNOME Shell)

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Gnome 3.28.2), the first NoAnnoyance plugin (by sindex) didn't work (it hid the notification but didn't show the dialog). The last NoAnnoyance plugin (by bjoerndaase) did work.